# How to catch a value inside a gridview row. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

im working on a MVC project.
How can i catch a value from a gridview row and save it as a variable?

What i want to do is, click on row, catch its value and delete it by a buttonclick.

Answer (score 0):

have u seen [GetStarted](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

u can make delete button
RAZOR

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

ASPX

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID }) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
```

and your controller

```
public ActionResult Delete(FormCollection fcNotUsed, int id = 0)
{
    var item = db.Source.Find(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    db.Source.Remove(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: i use Aspx page, not razor
and i want to select a row from gridview

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to do some action on appropriate grid row using jQuery?

While creating grid row you can assign to each one some specific attributes, like rowId, etc. Then create function which will be called on row click, get this attr values and call (using ajax or not) function from controller to delete this row.

?

Or just create submit button next to each row which will have an id and will call appropriate function.

Comment: The secound selution with submit button next to each row  isnt what i would like to have. 

could u please write a litle exemple about the function that can be called on row click ?